# Permission problems when mounting NFS folder

Tags: nfs

I've created an NFS Debian server with the following line in the exports file

```
/home/remote     10.255.255.108(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) 10.255.255.101(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash)
```

The directory belongs to a user and group with uid and gid that were set by me to known values.

On the client side I do (as root)

```
mount -t nfs pc00:/home/remote /home/NFS/
```

Now when I do ls -la on the directory in my PC I have the correct local user and group (which were created with the same GID and UID values as the user and group in the server)

```
drwxrwx---.  5 pepito      laspruebas   4096 Mar 28 11:55 NFS
```

However when I try to CD into the folder (as my user ariela):

```
[ariela@pc01 home]$ cd NFS/
bash: cd: NFS/: Permission denied
```

I should add that ariela belongs to group laspruebitas and If I try to cd into the folder when it is not mounted, there is no issue.

What am I doing wrong? I would like a solution that is not to set the folder permissions to 777.

EDIT: I have try entering the /home/NFS folder as root and cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this, I've solved this problem. But you need to make sure of two things: 1) that the group (in this case laspruebas) is your primary group. This can be accomplished permanently for the console with (`newgrep laspruebas`) or temporarily for one comand with `sg` AND 2) You must make sure that the directory has the x (execution permission) for the owner, group or others to be able to CD into it.